# Extending a homeomorphism from a dense set

Tags: gn.general-topology, measure-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Hausdorff topological spaces, and let $f : X \to Y$ be a Borel-measurable function. Suppose that $D \subseteq X$ is dense, that the image $f(D) \subseteq Y$ is dense, and that $f$ is a homeomorphism from $D$ to $f(D)$.

Does it follow that $f$ is a homeomorphism from $X$ to $Y$?

If not, is $f$ a measurable isomorphism from $X$ to $Y$?

Comment: The inclusion $f: (0, 1] \to [0, 1]$ with $D = X$??

Comment: @ToddTrimble: thanks, that's a clean counterexample.

Comment: Even continuity is not enough to deduce homoemorphism: look at the inclusion of a dense interval to the circle. For the second question, look at the inclusion of the rational numbers in the set of real numbers.

Comment: Something is strange: take $X=Y=\mathbb R$, $D=\mathbb Q$. Put $f(x)=x$ on $D$ and $f(x)=\sqrt 2$ on $X\setminus D$. I'm pretty sure you didn't have this idiotic example in mind, so what conditions are missing?

Comment: @fedja: Let me tell you more of my context, since these examples were not what I was thinking of. I have two Hausdorff linear spaces $X$ and $Y$, and a measurable linear map $f : X \to Y$. In the presence of some additional structure, I have Hilbert subspaces $H_X \subseteq X$ and $H_Y \subseteq Y$, and I've proved that the restriction map $f : H_X \to H_Y$ is an isomorphism. I would like to extend this isomorphism to the closure $\overline{H_X}$ in $X$. I had suspected it might be true for trivial topological reasons (hence this MO question), but it requires something subtler.

Comment: (voting to close, thanks everybody)

Comment: Take the Fourier transform from $L^p$ on the circle to $\ell^q$ ($p<2<q=\frac{p}{p-1}$) then. Looks like you'll need to disclose everything before we run out of stupid counterexamples :-).